# Adding preventDefault() and stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in coding in general, most especially javascript.

I made a flip div effect. But I noticed that when clicking one `.button` to trigger the flip effect, all the other divs that are similar in a page are also triggered. So I am trying to add both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` when flipping a div, so far its a big *FAIL*

As a starter, I came up with this code..

```
$('.insidecontent .button').click(function () {
    $('.insidecontent').addClass('flipped');
    $('.insidecontent').removeClass('unflipped');
});
$('.insidecontent .button-c').click(function () {
    $('.insidecontent').removeClass('flipped');
    $('.insidecontent').addClass('unflipped');
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/uriri/ke7kqvvk/3/

A friend of mine suggested that I should use `.parents()` on the current target inside the `.click()` function. But after reading the jQuery documentation, I am totally lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to stop click event or prevent default. You just need to flip right element. Right not you are adding/removing classes to/from all `.insidecontent`, while you need to select only parent element of the clicked button:

```
$('.insidecontent .button').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.insidecontent').addClass('flipped').removeClass('unflipped');
});
$('.insidecontent .button-c').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.insidecontent').removeClass('flipped').addClass('unflipped');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ke7kqvvk/5/

Or shorter optimized version can be:

```
$('.insidecontent').find('.button, .button-c').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.insidecontent').toggleClass('flipped unflipped');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ke7kqvvk/6/

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` won't help here. You need to use a selector that's more specific than all the elements with the same class.

```js
$('.insidecontent .button').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.insidecontent').addClass('flipped').removeClass('unflipped');
});
$('.insidecontent .button-c').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.insidecontent').removeClass('flipped').addClass('unflipped');
});
```

```css
.content{
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: box;

 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -moz-box-orient: vertical;
 box-orient: vertical;

 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -moz-box-align: center;
 box-align: center;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent {
 position: relative;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-perspective: 1000px;
 -o-perspective: 1000;
 perspective: 1000px;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent .front {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 900;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #ededed;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
 transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

._hasdata .insidecontent .front .fcontent {
 position:relative;
 top:30%;
 }

._hasdata .insidecontent.flipped .front {
 z-index: 900;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg);
 transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg);
}

._hasdata .insidecontent .back {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 800;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-180deg);
}

._hasdata .insidecontent.flipped .back {
 z-index: 1000;
 background: #E7E7E7;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
 transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

._hasdata .insidecontent .front,
._hasdata .insidecontent .back {
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent .button,
._hasdata .insidecontent.flipped .button-c {
 z-index: 15;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: -30px 20px 20px;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .1s linear;
 -moz-transition: opacity .1s linear;
 transition: opacity .1s linear;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent:hover .button,
._hasdata .insidecontent.flipped:hover .button-c {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent.unflipped .button-c {
 display: none;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent.flipped ._lar {
 height: 100%;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent.unflipped .bcontent {
 display: none;
}

._hasdata .insidecontent.flipped .bcontent {
 top: 30%;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <div class="_hasdata">
  <div class="insidecontent initalized unflipped">
   <div class="front">
                <span class="fcontent">FRONT CONTENT<br />HERE</span>
    <a class="btt button">info</a>
   </div>
   <div class="back _lar">
    <div class="bcontent">BACK INFO HERE</div>
    <a class="btt button-c">go back</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
     <div class="_hasdata">
  <div class="insidecontent initalized unflipped">
   <div class="front">
                <span class="fcontent">FRONT CONTENT<br />HERE</span>
    <a class="btt button">info</a>
   </div>
   <div class="back _exif">
    <div class="bcontent">BACK INFO HERE</div>
    <a class="btt button-c">go back</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you learned about the "[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)" keyword yet? In a JQuery click handler, *$(this)* refers to the element that the handler is called on. So, if you put removeClass and addClass methods on $(this) it will only affect that one element. You can traverse using this too... so your code would look like this:

```
    $('.insidecontent .button').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.insidecontent').addClass('flipped');
    $(this).parent().find('.insidecontent').removeClass('unflipped');
});

$('.insidecontent .button-c').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.insidecontent').removeClass('flipped');
    $(this).parent().find('.insidecontent').addClass('unflipped');
});
```

you may not even need the find method in your case, but it is better to be explicit.